# Centos 6.4 (64) skype 4.2 no sound notification

Tags: linux, centos, alsa, pulseaudio, skype

Everything works fine. I can hear and others can hear me. But no sound notification. In options -> sound devices "Make a test sound" button is disabled. Other button show "PulseAudio server (local)". At the bottom:It appears your system has PulseAudio running: to change sound settings you need to use your desktop manager volume control or PulseAudio volume control.

In gnome volume control alert is on and is unmuted. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Centos 6.5 with skype 4.3.
The skype did not see resource files. Fixed by creating a symbolic link "skype" pointing to folder where skype is installed:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/skype-4.3.0.37 skype
```